# What aquarium plant is this?

Tags: aquarium, aquatic-plants

I got this potted aquarium plant (unmarked) from my local fish store a few weeks ago thinking it was *Helanthium tenellum*, but now that it's growing out a bit I'm not sure what it is.

Would anyone be able to help identify it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here you can see some of the root, going straight down:
[image]

I didn't plant this one deep enough in the substrate, so you can see its roots and stem:
[image]

Comment: this is a hard question to answer,can you provide some sort of size of this plant,i have been looking in  my books to try to id the plant and it looks like a type of vallisneria but i can not give you a positive id.

Comment: @trondhansen Thanks for researching! The plants measure about 3 inches high, I took some more pictures that may be helpful! I will update my question with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top picture I think is *Najas guadalupensis*; I cannot find anything else it could be.

The plant in the last picture might be *Blyxa aubertii*, though I am not sure about this one.

It looks like you have two different types of plants in your tank, the *N. guadalupensis* have many other names like guppy grass and waternymph.

Plant identification is hard as a result of the natural variation of where they grow.